# Why is there a 0 in my header (on top of the indexes) after applying the .sum()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, series

This is my dataframe with i) columns representing the player names, ii) rows representing each game round, and iii) values representing whether they participated in each game round.

```
tdf = df[unique_players][mask]
tdf

              Player A | Player B | Player C | Player D | Player E
         10          0 |        1 |        1 |        0 |        1
         44          0 |        0 |        1 |        1 |        1
         45          0 |        0 |        1 |        1 |        1
         56          0 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1
```

Somehow, when I apply tdf.sum(), I get a weird 0 on top of my index column. I also tried to convert into dataframe, or reset_index() and see if the 0 goes away, but it does not.

```
tdf.sum()

0                  << THIS IS THE WEIRD 0 
Player A        0
Player B        2
Player C        4
Player D        3
Player E        4
```

Tried to convert into a dataframe, but this is the output.

```
|          | 0 |
| 0        |   |
| -------- | - |
| Player A | 0 |
| Player B | 0 |
| Player C | 0 |
| Player D | 0 |
| Player E | 0 |

Real example of how it looks in my jupyter lab. Output snippet link below.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP4b1.png

Comment: I tried with dummy data in a Jupyter notebook and did not get a 0. Are you using Jupyter too

Comment: Yes I am using Jupyter. Yes I also tried with dummy data and it does not have the same issue… @Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why the issue was occurring, it was because I had a line of code `df.columns = df.iloc[0]` that causes this issue.

Sample screenshot here to show the problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDxMK.png